# Leaving website callback in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to run function when user leaves the specific website? Also how handle another tabs are in web browser opened with same URL? I completely don't know how to go about it. For example, I have two tabs with www.burito.com. I want to run function when last tab with www.burrito.com is closed. Thanks.

Comment: Did you google "Is there a way to run function when user leaves the specific website"? It gives answers.

Comment: Which behaviour are you looking for with the other tabs?

Comment: I mean, I have two tabs with www.burito.com. I want to run function when last tab with www.burrito.com is closed

Comment: What exactly do you want to do when the tab is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this? (using jQuery)

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
 //your stuff
});
```

Comment: will it handle website in another tabs?

Answer (score 1):

In html

```
<script>
function myUnLoad() {
}
</script>
<body onunload="myUnLoad()">
```

Comment: will it handle website in another tabs?

Comment: Tabs are independent. It is hard for one tab to get info about an other tab for security reasons. You will probably need to filter that out on your server.